# Getting the location of a folder next to my .jar file

Tags: java

In a program I am making, I need to access images in a folder placed alongside it. The program works fine when I run it with Eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar file, it does not get the location of the folder properly.

```
File roomF = new File("Assets/Rooms/1/0.png");
```

In the IDE, `roomF` refers to the correct location:

> C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\Eclipse Java\[Project name]\Assets\Rooms\1\0.png

However, in the .jar file, it refers to this:

> C:\Users\[Username]\Assets\Rooms\1\0.png.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In java you should put resources in folder resources. You can read about this here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have resources outside of your JAR or dependencies that need a local path in order to work. Create a resource folder in your project and load the file from there.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access files inside the resource folder? I'm using JFrame if that matters.

Comment: Create the resource folder and then expand the JAR to check the path. Another solution to copy the file from the JAR to a temporary directory and load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Place your JAR at:

   > 'C:\Users[Username]\Desktop\Eclipse Java'

This way, when you are accessing `Assets/Rooms/1/0.png`, it points to the correct location.

2. Make a folder where you will place your JAR everytime. Create the path 'Assets/Rooms/1' in the folder and place your file `0.png` there, hence you wouldn't be needing to place your JAR each time you make a new one as said in step 1.